# Client not Able to Register on the server hosted on AWS using Symmetric DS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sqlite, symmetricds

I am trying to deploy a bidirectional sync functionality using Symmetric DS 3.12, with the server side hosted on AWS. The client side properties and the server side properties files are shown.

```
# server-000.properties
engine.name=server-000
db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.url=jdbc:sqlite:./server1.sqlite
db.user=symmetric
db.password=
registration.url=
sync.url=http://172.31.3.23:31415/sync/server-000
group.id=server
external.id=000
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
jobs.synchronized.enable=true
sync.triggers.thread.count.per.server=1
```

```
# client-001.properties
engine.name=client-001
db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.url=jdbc:sqlite:./client001.sqlite
db.user=symmetric
db.password=
sync.url=http://3.141.31.76:31415/sync/server-000
registration.url=http://3.141.31.76:31415/sync/server-000
group.id=client
external.id=001
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
jobs.synchronized.enable=true
sync.triggers.thread.count.per.server=1
```

I followed the following link for setting up the configuration:
https://houseofbrick.com/replicating-from-oracle-on-premise-to-oracle-in-aws-rds-using-symmetricds/.
Initially I tried using the security groups from the AWS-EC2 console to expose ports 31415 (as explained in the following link):
https://kerneltalks.com/virtualization/how-to-open-port-on-aws-ec2-linux-server/.
But it did not work out. It always shows the port to be closed.
Then I tried using the Dockerfile and exposed the ports, which passed the ping-pong test. Then I tried opening registration for the client side. It does not show any error but does not register at the server side.
The log at the client side are as follows:

```
2021-02-20 15:49:36,330 INFO [startup] [SymmetricWebServer] [main] About to start SymmetricDS web server on 0.0.0.0:31415:HTTP/1.1
2021-02-20 15:49:37,331 INFO [startup] [SymmetricEngineHolder] [main] Current directory is /home/ysharshit/Documents/TE/KrishnaIkaP/bws-app-v2/server_sync
2021-02-20 15:49:37,331 INFO [startup] [SymmetricEngineHolder] [main] Starting in single-server mode
2021-02-20 15:49:38,321 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Initializing connection to database
2021-02-20 15:49:39,051 INFO [client-001] [JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Detected database 'SQLite', version '3', protocol 'sqlite'
2021-02-20 15:49:39,096 INFO [client-001] [JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] The IDatabasePlatform being used is org.jumpmind.db.platform.sqlite.SqliteDatabasePlatform
2021-02-20 15:49:39,732 INFO [client-001] [SqliteJdbcSymmetricDialect] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.sqlite.SqliteJdbcSymmetricDialect
2021-02-20 15:49:39,963 INFO [client-001] [ExtensionService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Found 0 extension points from the database that will be registered
2021-02-20 15:49:40,200 INFO [client-001] [StagingManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] The staging directory was initialized at the following location: /home/ysharshit/Documents/TE/KrishnaIkaP/bws-app-v2/server_sync/tmp/client-001
2021-02-20 15:49:45,462 INFO [client-001] [ExtensionService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Found 0 extension points from the database that will be registered
2021-02-20 15:49:45,463 INFO [client-001] [ClientExtensionService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Found 8 extension points from spring that will be registered
2021-02-20 15:49:45,497 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Initializing SymmetricDS database
2021-02-20 15:49:45,497 INFO [client-001] [SqliteJdbcSymmetricDialect] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Checking if SymmetricDS tables need created or altered
2021-02-20 15:49:45,657 INFO [startup] [SymmetricWebServer] [main] Joining the web server main thread
2021-02-20 15:49:45,932 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Done initializing SymmetricDS database
2021-02-20 15:49:45,932 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] SymmetricDS database version : 3.12.6
2021-02-20 15:49:45,933 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] SymmetricDS software version : 3.12.6
2021-02-20 15:49:45,935 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting registered node [group=client, id=001, nodeId=001]
2021-02-20 15:49:45,956 INFO [client-001] [ClusterService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] This node picked a server id of ysharshit-X550LD
2021-02-20 15:49:45,957 INFO [client-001] [TriggerRouterService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Synchronizing triggers
2021-02-20 15:49:45,965 INFO [client-001] [TriggerRouterService] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Done synchronizing triggers
2021-02-20 15:49:45,978 INFO [client-001] [RouterJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Routing on periodic schedule: every 5000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.344+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,014 INFO [client-001] [PushJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Push on periodic schedule: every 10000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.379+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,014 INFO [client-001] [PullJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Pull on periodic schedule: every 10000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.380+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,015 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Offline Push not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,015 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Offline Pull not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,017 INFO [client-001] [OutgoingPurgeJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting job 'Purge Outgoing' with cron expression: '0 0 */4 * * *'
2021-02-20 15:49:46,019 INFO [client-001] [IncomingPurgeJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting job 'Purge Incoming' with cron expression: '0 0 */4 * * *'
2021-02-20 15:49:46,019 INFO [client-001] [StatisticFlushJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting job 'Stat Flush' with cron expression: '0 0/5 * * * *'
2021-02-20 15:49:46,020 INFO [client-001] [SyncTriggersJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting job 'SyncTriggers' with cron expression: '0 0 0 * * *'
2021-02-20 15:49:46,021 INFO [client-001] [HeartbeatJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Heartbeat on periodic schedule: every 900000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.387+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,021 INFO [client-001] [WatchdogJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Watchdog on periodic schedule: every 3600000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.387+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,022 INFO [client-001] [StageManagementJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting job 'Stage Management' with cron expression: '0 0 * * * *'
2021-02-20 15:49:46,023 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Refresh Cache not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,023 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job File Sync Tracker not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,023 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job File Sync Pull not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,023 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job File Sync Push not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,023 INFO [client-001] [InitialLoadExtractorJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Initial Load Extract on periodic schedule: every 10000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.389+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,024 INFO [client-001] [MonitorJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Monitor on periodic schedule: every 60000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.390+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,024 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Report Status not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,024 INFO [client-001] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Log Miner not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 15:49:46,025 INFO [client-001] [InitialLoadJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Initial Load Queue on periodic schedule: every 10000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T15:49:53.391+0530
2021-02-20 15:49:46,030 INFO [client-001] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] SymmetricDS Node STARTED:
     nodeId=001
     groupId=client
     type=server
     subType=null
     name=client-001
     softwareVersion=3.12.6
     databaseName=SQLite
     databaseVersion=3.32
     driverName=SQLite JDBC
     driverVersion=3.32.3.2
     uptime=0 sec.
2021-02-20 15:49:53,412 INFO [client-001] [DataGapFastDetector] [client-001-job-1] Full gap analysis is running
2021-02-20 15:49:53,415 INFO [client-001] [DataGapFastDetector] [client-001-job-1] Querying data in gaps from database took 2 ms
2021-02-20 15:49:53,415 INFO [client-001] [DataGapFastDetector] [client-001-job-1] Full gap analysis is done after 2 ms
```

Logs at the server side:

```
s with the first run at 2021-02-20T10:48:27.841+0000
2021-02-20 10:48:18,101 INFO [server-000] [MonitorJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Monitor on periodic schedule: every 60000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T10:48:27.842+0000
2021-02-20 10:48:18,101 INFO [server-000] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Report Status not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 10:48:18,102 INFO [server-000] [JobManager] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Job Log Miner not configured for auto start
2021-02-20 10:48:18,102 INFO [server-000] [InitialLoadJob] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Starting Initial Load Queue on periodic schedule: every 10000ms with the first run at 2021-02-20T10:48:27.843+0000
2021-02-20 10:48:18,104 INFO [server-000] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] SymmetricDS Node STARTED:
     nodeId=000
     groupId=server
     type=server
     subType=null
     name=server-000
     softwareVersion=3.12.6
     databaseName=SQLite
     databaseVersion=3.32
     driverName=SQLite JDBC
     driverVersion=3.32.3.2
     uptime=0 sec.
2021-02-20 10:48:27,824 INFO [server-000] [DataService] [server-000-job-1] Inserting missing last data gap: { startId: 1, endId: 50000001, createTime: "Sat Feb 20 10:48:27 UTC 2021" }
2021-02-20 10:48:27,836 INFO [server-000] [DataGapFastDetector] [server-000-job-1] Full gap analysis is running
2021-02-20 10:48:27,837 INFO [server-000] [DataGapFastDetector] [server-000-job-1] Querying data in gaps from database took 0 ms
2021-02-20 10:48:27,838 INFO [server-000] [DataGapFastDetector] [server-000-job-1] Full gap analysis is done after 2 ms
2021-02-20 10:48:27,839 INFO [server-000] [PushHeartbeatListener] [server-000-job-4] Some attribute(s) of node changed.  Recording changes
2021-02-20 10:48:27,840 INFO [server-000] [PushHeartbeatListener] [server-000-job-4] Updating my node configuration info according to the symmetric properties
2021-02-20 10:48:27,858 INFO [server-000] [NodeCommunicationService] [server-000-job-3] pull will use 10 threads
2021-02-20 10:48:33,007 INFO [server-000] [ConfigurationChangedDataRouter] [server-000-job-9] About to refresh the cache of nodes because new configuration came through the data router
```

Why is the client side not registering at the server side? I have taken care of the public and private IPs that AWS provides.Exposing ports using AWS should ideally be done using the security group itself - it didn't work out. What is it that I am missing?

I will be extremely grateful if I can receive help on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sync URL at the server should be the same as the registration URL at the client. Both URLs at the client seems having equal IP address and the port

Comment: I agree with Boris, the registration.url on the client is wrong it should be registration.url=http://172.31.3.23:31415/sync/server-000